# Point of checkdigits in MRZs?

Tags: standards

Not sure if this is the right subreddit to ask this question, but I will give it a shot. There is the ICAO standard for Machine Readable Zones as described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_passport. I don't see the point for check digits there.

If I have F instead of 5 for example in the MRZ code somewhere in the second line for example, all the checkdigits will be the same. What is the point in the first place for those check digits in the ICAO standard? Especially I don't see the point of the last check digits calculation since you could also calculate it by using the check digits from the second line and not all the letters/numbers.

Could someone explain why we need those checkdigits?

Answer (score 1):

To be fair. This is not a subreddit. Anyway, there are multiple reasons that there are check digits inside the MRZ. The first reason is that automatic readers can check if the code is read well enough. The second reason is that it prevents a lot of fraud and identification theft. Some people that alter their travel documents do not know that there are check digits in place. So some people will get caught because they fail to edit the numbers.

Some countries now include PDF417 barcodes and/or QR-codes to reach better reads by machines. But keep in mind that not all governments/countries have access to high-tech devices, so the machine readable zone is still mandatory for a check with the naked eye.

Source: I work for a travel document verification company.

Comment: An eMRTD ID has an NFC chip inside which is cryptographicaly protected. The MRZ is used as access password for its Basic Access Control or `BAC`. If `MRZ` is incorrect then access is denied. How important is an MRZ check digit considering that the chip is also doing a cryptographic check. Can an MRZ check digit be skipped? Some ID cards have wrong check digit values. Hope to hear your professional opinion. Thank you

Comment: The check digits only tell you if the MRZ has been read correctly by your system. Some specimen do have wrong check digits indeed. This to prevent them from going through automated systems. Some (amateurs) that make fake passports forget to update the check digits, resulting in a faulty MRZ.

Answer (score 0):

MRZ check digits are calculated on subsections of the entire MRZ. Each calculation serves as a check for each section. A final check digit is calculated on the sum of each sections and this digit serves as a double check of the individual check.

The below have same check digit of 8:

- 123456780
- 128456785

Whereas the subsection check digit matched after the tampering but the final check digit will detect this. Therefore, the final check digit adds additional robustness.

Although, I am wondering whether this visual check digit is mandatory because an eMRTD NFC chip **BAC** protocol also does a much stronger cryptographic check of the MRZ value.

**UPDATES**: My original claim that the composite check digit adds robustness to tampering is incorrect. Given the below TD1 MRZ:

```
IDSLV0012345678<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
9306026F2708252SLV<<<<<<<<<<<4
JOHN<SMEAGOL<<WENDY<LIESSETTEF
```

An OCR scanner can either gave `0012345678` or `OO12345678` for the document number portion and all check digits passes including the composite check digit. But there is no way to tell which document number is correct. It seems that an MRZ check digit has edge cases that cannot be helped.